# Олелюшечки ― это что?

Tags: значение-слов, литература

Помните мультфильм про домовёнка Кузю?

Там есть эпизод, когда девочка Наташа даёт Кузе торт с цветочками и листочками, а домовёнок ей отвечает:
― Это  я не ем. Я ― не козел.

Этот мультфильм снят по книге Татьяны Александровой "Кузька в новом доме". Как раз сейчас читал её. Там этот домовёнок в начале всё время говорит девочке слова, которая та не понимает и переспрашивает.

> -- Дряпать тоже не будешь?
> -- А что такое "дряпать"?
>
> Незнакомец засмеялся, запрыгал,  веник
> заходил ходуном.  Наташа кое-как
> разобрала  сквозь шуршание  и смех,что
> "дряпать" и  "царапать" -- примерно
> одно и то же, и твердо пообещала  не
> царапаться,  ведь она -- человек, а не
> кошка. Прутья  у веника раздвинулись,
> на девочку посмотрели блестящие черные
> глаза, и она услышала:
>
> -- Может, и свориться не будешь?
>
> Что такое "свориться", Наташа опять не
> знала. Вот уж лохматик обрадовался,
> заплясал, запрыгал, руки-ноги
> болтались и высовывались за веником во
> все стороны.
>
> -- Ах, беда-беда-огорчение! Что ни  скажешь  -- не  по  разуму,  что ни
> молвишь -- все попусту, что ни
> спросишь -- все без толку!

Слова "дряпать", "свариться" и ещё другие, которые я не цитировал, мне понятны и без объяснений. Есть такие слова.

**А вот слово "олелюшечки" ― что это значит?** 
Ниже я процитирую отрывок. Я что-то не припомню такого. Такое слово вообще существует? В каких краях?

В книге девочка Кузю угощает не тортом, а пирожными, тоже с цветочками. И вот их Кузя называет **"олелюшечки"**.

> Кузька  обернулся  к   Наташе  и 
> заявил,  что олелюшечек никак не
> хватит.
>
> -- Чего не хватит? -- рассеянно спросила  девочка. Она  все думала,
> что сказать маме о пирожных (...).
>
> --  Олелюшечек,  говорю, на всех не  хватит.  Не красна изба углами,  а
> красна пирогами. Эдаких вот, с
> цветами! -- Кузька даже рассердился 
> и, видя, что девочка не понимает, о
> чем речь, ткнул  пальцем  в пирожные:
> -- Вот они, олелюшечки,  эти  самые  пироги  цветочные!  Я  ж   говорю, 
> невразумиха  ты непонятливая, а еще
> смеешься!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В словаре Даля есть ОЛЕЛЮХА ж. костр. колоб, колобок, клоцка; | *болван, разиня. 
  Олелюшечка, получается, маленькая олелюха (колобок, пирожок)